# Why Windows can't see USB drive?

Tags: windows, usb, partitioning, drivers, hard-drive-recovery

I was playing with live boot USB, and somehow it got corrupted. When I plug it into my PC it said it needs to format the USB. But when formatting it spat out an error along the lines of: "Windows can't format it." I also tried diskpart to no effect.

I then found something on Internet about Minitool partition wizard and when I was playing with it I somehow pressed `wipe`, and now it is full of zeros. I can see it in device manager, but not in disk management. I tried restarting pc, changing USB ports, different computer, and reinstalling drivers, and now I am starting to get afraid that I lost my USB.

Summary: I have a USB full of zeros that is showing in device manager but not anywhere else.

I tried restarting computer, different computer, and reinstalling drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably been writing lots of data to a USB that was already near to
its end-of-life.

This activity caused the USB to finally die.

It's time to get a new USB.